# Illustrator Basic fill patterns

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Where are the simple fill patterns such as diagonal parallel lines or regular texture.  Adobe CS5   Mac OS X 10.10.3 27"iMac

Comment: Hi Judy, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please be a bit more specific? Are you looking for the actual files (Scott's answer) or how to access them within Illustrator? Please [edit] your question with this info. Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

`Adobe Illustrator CS5 > Presets > [your language] > Swatches > Patterns`

Answer (score 0):

Open the *Swatches* palette and open its options (the three lines and triangle on the panel's top left). Then click through to <kbd>Open Swatch Library > Patterns</kbd> and pick your choice of basic patterns.

This will pop up a new swatches palette with the swatches in that library. You can easily browse through different libraries using the forward and back arrows on the bottom of the new palette.